# Show echo define in if-else condition

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert a constant define within the code, so that if there is $error[] it is possible to insert the string corresponding define. In my case:

```
if($user->login($username,$password)){ 

    header('Location: memberpage.php');
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
    exit;
} else {
    $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';

}
```

define constant

```
define ('ERROR_LOGIN', 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.');
```

how do I insert ERROR_LOGIN after $error[] so that I'll be back the rest if the condition is false?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store your constant into the array like this:

```
$error[] = ERROR_LOGIN;
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/199024)

Comment: @akmed in you question you mention `INDEX_ERROR` as well, what did you exactly called it

Comment: I'll explain more simply, I need to replace - Wrong username or password or your account hasnt Been activated.- the first part of the code with the constant define...

Comment: `insert ERROR_LOGIN after $error[] so that I'll be back the rest if the condition is false?` read this yourself, it s not clear at all

Comment: @akmed It doesn't work? That's a totally different error message. You've not created `login()` method in the user class.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I dont think the point is coming across `:(` and also redirecting before setting a session is not a good idea

Comment: @meda Ugh `:/` Anyway, I've upvoted you because it's the correct answer

Comment: solved, the problem was inexplicably includes the file containing the constants define